# Different between getters and func getSomething()?

Tags: swift, getter-setter

[image]

what is the different between getter of mFirstName variable, and instance method getFirstName()? If i have the first, why do i need another get method?

Comment: *"why do i need another get method?"* – You don't. That code looks like a literal translation from some other language. Have a look at "Properties" in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter of the variable is always executed. The only exception to that is when you get or set variables inside of init. This is the swift way of implementing getters and setters. Languages like Java do not have this option so you have to create getter and setter functions.

IMO providing getters and setters on your variable is safer. This way you ensure that they are always called. If you have getter and setter functions and modify a variable directly and forget to call the setters and getters it can lead to weird errors.

Comment: At first, thank you on your answer, but i have another question. Im translating some code from Java to Swift. And if i have in Java getters and setters and some func like : public String getGradeByLabel(BigDecimal percentage) {

         for (GradingSystemLabelTo label : getLabels()) ....

How would i wrote something like getLabels in Swift?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The for loop? It'd be for label in labels. But there are other questions even on SO that have answered these questions with way more details.

Comment: Yes i mean exactly on the code inside the loop, how would you translate it?
Thank you very much on help

Comment: Like I said. for label in labels

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake..i see now